# Gradle dependency in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Due to some issue i format my laptop and install the android studio again but now i am not being able to work in it. I cannot create the new project in it. When ever i tried it show this kind of error. The problem of gradle dependency download. I try some solution from the google like downloading the gradle manually and link it through the setting but it didnt work. How can i solve this ??[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g7mx.png).. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think your Android Studio gradle settings are set to offline, could you please verify this?

Comment: Didn't get you.

Comment: Its not offline there is no check in setting>gradle,deplyoment,build>gradle and offline

Comment: Weird, try invalidating the cache and restart

Comment: removed the cache folder and restart but didnt work